# SCNShadable behavior for SCNGeometry and SCNMaterial

Tags: swift, scenekit, metal

Both of SCNGeometry and SCNMaterial does conform SCNShadable protocol(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable), but I can't figure out what is logical difference between setting `program` property to geometry and set to material. What if I'll set different programs to SCNGeometry and for its material(single for simplicity)?

Comment: Have you tried setting one property and see if the other one is updated? It’s possible that setting the program of a geometry updates the program of the material it has.